# Can't add services to diaspora pod

Tags: diaspora

I've setup a diaspora pod on Debian box, diaspora.ivvy.ru, but can't seem to figure out why "connect to..." links not showing up under services tab.

I register a twitter app, copy-paste twitter consumer key/secret to application.yml and oauth_key.yml.

I cloned diaspora from github just yesterday.

I think it's ssl issue but there are no signs of failure in log files or anything and my cert is accepted by all modern browsers.

My cert is a startssl class 1 one.

I'm not really familiar with ruby so hacking code is quite a problem for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

There was quite misleading syntax in `oauth_keys.yml`:

```
tumblr:
  consumer_key: <%= AppConfig['tumblr_consumer_key'] %>
  consumer_secret: <%= AppConfig['tumblr_consumer_secret'] %>
```

I thought you need to just replace `tumblr_consumer_key` with your own key but the correct syntax is:

```
tumblr:
  consumer_key: 'enter_your_key'
  consumer_secret: 'enter_your_secret'
```

I think the diaspora devs should've pointed that out in docs somewhere.